# Nightwatch correct way to get api result to populate variable then run tests that use that variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, nightwatch.js

I am new to node and the async way of doing things.

I want to create and run a test suite using nightwatch.js, I have read all the docs and I'm baffled at how to do what I want (been working on it for 3 days already).

Am I thinking about this the wrong way?

```
module.exports = {
    before: function(browser) {
        /*
        Here I just want to make a web call to an api and get a result and then
        store that result in a variable which we will use later in test1 and other test cases
        */
        browser.globals.myVariable = resultofsomeapicalll;
        //wait here until proceeding
    },
    after: function(browser) {
        browser.end();
    },
    beforeEach: function(browser) {
    },
    afterEach: function() {
    },
    'test1': function(browser) {
        browser.url(browser.launchUrl + browser.globals.myVariable, function(result) {
            browser.waitForElementPresent('body', 1000);
            browser.expect.element("#something").to.be.present;
            browser.saveScreenshot('./screenshots/' + browser.currentTest.module + '/' + browser.currentTest.name + '.png');
        });
    },
};
```

Comment: What's the problem? Is the test not running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform asynchronous task in the Nightwatch.JS before[Each] or after[Each] hooks, you need to pass an callback argument to the function, which you trigger once the job is done.

In below example, it would be an API Call using [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) library;

```
module.exports = {
    before: function(browser, done) {
        axios.get('https://example.com/api?ID=12345')
          .then(function (response) {
            browser.globals.myVariable = response;
            done();
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            done(error);
          });
    },
    after: function(browser) {
        browser.end();
    },
    beforeEach: function(browser) {
    },
    afterEach: function() {
    },
    'test1': function(browser) {
        console.log()
    },
};
```

> **Controlling the done invocation timeout**
>
> By default the done invocation timeout is set to 10 seconds (2 seconds
>   for unit tests). In some cases this might not be sufficient and to
>   avoid a timeout error, you can increase this timeout by defining an
>   asyncHookTimeout property (in milliseconds) in your external globals
>   file (see below for details on external globals).

http://nightwatchjs.org/guide/#asynchronous-before-each-and-after-each-

Best regards,

Riku

Comment: Thanks @Riku I think I am going to cry....

I even read that in the documentation but I didn't quite grasp the concept. So it seems like the before function must implement its own kind of polling to wait until something is set by the done function and then returns. I wish your example was in the documentation. Awesome answer with example, thanks mate.